# External NTFS drive mounted as root, can modify but not add file

Tags: linux, debian, mount, ntfs

When I mount an external NTFS drive on my Debian Jessie,i can modify existing files but not copy new files on it. It says that I don't have the permission but I'm root. I've also try to add `-o umask=000` to the `mount` command but the problem remains.

This is the on the fly mount, nothing in the `fstab` or anywhere else.

If someone has an idea...

Thanks

Comment: Please post the row corresponding to this partition from the output of `mount`.